# The module has not been deployed problem in NetBeans Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, netbeans, ide

When I create a new web project on NetBeans the project runs fine but after adding Spring library on the project I got this type of error. What's the reason for the problem?

- JDK version: 19
- NetBeans IDE version: 15
- Tomcat version: apache-tomcat-10.0.27
- Spring version: spring-framework-5.3.9

Here is the Application log:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication2 -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication2 run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Incrementally deploying http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2
Completed incremental distribution of http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2
Incrementally redeploying http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2
Deploy is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAdmin%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext566804997520945144.xml&path=/WebApplication2
FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/WebApplication2] but context failed to start
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1163: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Here is the server log:

```
23-Nov-2022 00:13:00.540 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/WebApplication2]
23-Nov-2022 00:13:01.057 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/WebApplication2]
23-Nov-2022 00:14:30.343 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-38] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [D:\Software\Code Related Apps\JAVA\apache-tomcat-10.0.27\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication2.xml]
23-Nov-2022 00:14:30.344 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-38] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/WebApplication2] in deployment descriptor [D:\Software\Code Related Apps\JAVA\apache-tomcat-10.0.27\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication2.xml] has been ignored
23-Nov-2022 00:14:30.472 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-38] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [D:\Software\Code Related Apps\JAVA\apache-tomcat-10.0.27\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication2.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:693)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1780)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1592)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:1027)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:358)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:683)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:661)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1762)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebApplication2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering. Duplicate fragments found in [[file:/C:/Users/Admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication2/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/Admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication2/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.9-sources.jar]].
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2281)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2237)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5085)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 45 more
23-Nov-2022 00:14:30.633 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-38] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [D:\Software\Code Related Apps\JAVA\apache-tomcat-10.0.27\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication2.xml] has finished in [290] ms
23-Nov-2022 00:14:39.841 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-29] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/WebApplication2]
23-Nov-2022 00:14:39.857 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-30] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [D:\Software\Code Related Apps\JAVA\apache-tomcat-10.0.27\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication2.xml]
23-Nov-2022 00:14:39.859 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-30] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/WebApplication2] in deployment descriptor [D:\Software\Code Related Apps\JAVA\apache-tomcat-10.0.27\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication2.xml] has been ignored
23-Nov-2022 00:14:39.977 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-30] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [D:\Software\Code Related Apps\JAVA\apache-tomcat-10.0.27\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication2.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:693)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1780)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1592)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:1027)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:358)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:683)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:661)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1762)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebApplication2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering. Duplicate fragments found in [[file:/C:/Users/Admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication2/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/Admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication2/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.9-sources.jar]].
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2281)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2237)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5085)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 45 more
23-Nov-2022 00:14:40.014 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-30] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [D:\Software\Code Related Apps\JAVA\apache-tomcat-10.0.27\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication2.xml] has finished in [156] ms
```

Let me know if you know the solution please.

*Note: I do not know the Spring framework yet I just added the library for learning.*

Comment: `See the server log for details.` - Can you show us the relevant error from the server log?

Comment: server log added @andrewJames

Comment: OK, thank you. I did say "relevant"... but do you see that "caused by" message buried in there? `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found.` You can research that. Also you can take a Spring tutorial, instead of just adding Spring and hoping it works.